# networkx: compute shortest distance from all nodes in a subset to each of the nodes in another subset

Tags: networkx, shortest-path

I know networkx contains a host of shortest path length algorithms, for example: **shortest_path_length**.

However, all these algorithms pick as argument either the whole set of nodes in a network or pairs of nodes.

At the same time, I am aware networkx contains a function betweenness_centrality_subset which allows to compute the betwenness from all nodes in a subset A to all nodes in a subset B (with A=B possibly). It is easy to serialize such function as showed in here:

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/algorithms/plot_parallel_betweenness.html

I would like to know if anything of the sort has been developed for any of the in-built shortest path functions.

thanks

I tried to build a function which takes as input a bunch of nodes but I fail to understand how to work the problem out